# MySql DATE_ADD function is throwing BLOB for Timestamp addition

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I tried with below query , its failing to add seconds to timestamp value

```
select DATE_ADD('2012-02-27 00:00:00', INTERVAL 3600 second) as new_time
```

Output is showing as

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work on sql fiddle. [Your original Code tested on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/6844)

Give this a try,

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(CAST('2012-02-27 00:00:00' AS DATETIME), INTERVAL 3600 second) as new_time
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/6845)